# How do focus and activation of controls relate?

Tags: winforms, focus, infragistics

I am trying to understand how the "active" and "focused" states are handled for windows and controls and hierarchies thereof.

This is a very broad question so here is my actual problem to illustrate a bit:

I have a control that calls this.Focus() in some cases. This control is shown in an Infragistics dropdown. When the control calls this.Focus() the Deactivated event is raised on the main window of the application which results in the dropdown being closed. Which of course shouldn't happen if you try to get focus.

I need to figure out if there is some way to declare this control a child of the main window so that the main window will not get a "deactivate" just because the child wants focus. I'm not even sure that's possible, though and I can't find any documentation on these events. ([Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.deactivate.aspx) is the MS documentation for your amusement.)

Comment: I recommend posting an example on the Infragistics forums here so Infragistics can tell you how to correct the issue and fix the behavior if needed: http://www.infragistics.com/community/forums/86.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There's a dedicated Window message that signals that a window is activated, the WM_ACTIVATE message.  It is the one that generates the Form.Activated event.  Windows only sends it to top-level windows.  In other words, windows that are not embedded in a larger window and don't have a parent.  A custom dropdown window can resemble a top-level window, its distinguishing feature is that it is able to extend outside the bounds of the window on which it is hosted.  The dropdown of a ComboBox is an example.

That this generates the Deactivated event for the form when you give it the focus is just a bug.  They didn't give the window the correct parent.  Contact Infragistics for support.

Comment: So what is the relationship between activate and focus? The top-level window gets WM_ACTIVATE and some control is focused?

Answer (score 0):

As I recall, activation is a form level thing, while Focus is a control level one, so in an application, one form will be active and one control on that form can have focus.

Is the control you are calling Focus on part of the main form?

Comment: What is the definition of "part of the main form"? Sorry, if this is a dumb question. :)

Comment: That's OK, I wasn't very clear; can you explain the forms in the application. Is there a single form, or are you having problems with events occurring on two different forms?

Comment: There are multiple forms an the form that wants focus is a control that pops up in a datagridview that is an sub-window of the main window. (Infragistics docking manager sub-window)

Comment: I agree with Hans, smells like an issue around the Infragistics infrastructure so give them a try